# android add java.lang.management API

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Now I have a problem with Android non-supported libraries. In fact it does not support this API: "java.lang.management".
Eclipse shows me this error :

**10-25 17:53:03.460: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.**

I wonder how I can add this API to be supported by my android application.

Any help please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That API is not a part of Android, and is not compatible with Android.

The `java.lang.management` API is for managing and monitoring the Java VM. Android's Dalvik VM is not a Java VM.

Comment: ok but we can not make something like this: https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages ?

Comment: Sure you can give repackaging a try, but I don't think you are going to have much success with the majority of the management package. The management API is expecting a completely different VM, so none of the functionality can be guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with Android Version 23, situation has slightly improved. For example I found a replacement for:

```
GarbageCollectorMXBean gb = ....
long gctime = gb.getCollectionTime();
```

Thanks to @Jacob, I am now using this code. First the `getRuntimeStat()` method is not available in all android versions. So I am doing some reflection first:

```
static {
  try {
      Class<?> debugClass = Debug.class;
      getRuntimeStat = debugClass.getDeclaredMethod(
           "getRuntimeStat", String.class);
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
      getRuntimeStat = null;
  }
}
```

Retrieving the GC time is then a matter of calling the method handle, with the correct property name. I am currently using this property name:

```
String gctimestr;
try {
    gctimestr = (String) (getRuntimeStat != null ? 
         getRuntimeStat.invoke(null, "art.gc.gc-time") : null);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    gctimestr = null;
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    gctimestr = null;
}
```

The `gctimestr` can then be converted to a long value, if its non-null. On the other hand if its null the statistics is not available, through this API.