# Kafka Producer on Android

Tags: android, apache-kafka

I would like to use an Android client as a Kafka Producer.
When I try to send a record to the topic I'm getting following error:

**Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory**

on this line:

`mProducer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);`

I am below the limit for the amount of methods:

```
Total methods in mobile-debug.apk: 52200 (79.65% used) 
Total fields in mobile-debug.apk:  21143 (32.26% used)
```

**What can be the reason that causes this error?**

By the way, I wasn't able to find any example where kafka producer was used on an Android or iOS.

### Update 1

In addition to the answer of Borys Zibrov, seems that nobody ported it successfully. These threads are also 2 years old.

- https://qnalist.com/questions/5017593/has-anybody-successfully-integrated-kafka-jar-for-android-app
- https://www.quora.com/In-Apache-Kafka-Can-we-have-mobiles-Android-or-IOS-Devices-as-Consumers-What-is-your-take-on-this

### Update 2

Regarding the ManagementFactory class, see this question:
[android add java.lang.management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595814/android-add-java-lang-management-api)

Comment: maybe you can share your code and your dependecies, so i will have a look on it.

Comment: There is really nothing special. Just plain Producer code from the examples.

Comment: I use this code: https://github.com/lidox/big-data-fun/blob/master/kafka-flink-101/src/main/java/com/artursworld/Producer.java trying to get it work on android

Comment: Have you found any solutions to run Kafka on Android? I need any materials that can be provided? In Android i wasn't able to find any documents about Kafka to run as neither consumer nor producer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually not sure it's possible to use Kafka as a producer on Android (see for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043532/how-to-use-android-app-as-a-producing-client-for-kafka) question, not answered at the moment of writing), because of the dependencies involved. So, someone might have ported Kafka to Android but I don't know that.

I could suggest a simple alternative: [REST service that posts data to Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest), and Android App will just call this service.

Answer (score 1):

That API is not a part of Android, and is not compatible with Android. 
The java.lang.management API is for managing and monitoring the Java VM. Android's Dalvik VM is not a Java VM.

Answer (score 0):

Your kafka servers should not be accessible to clients that increase security risks.We usually use kafka for async inter service communications and restrict access to our kafka servers to predefined computers.