# how can I add java.lang.management.ManagementFactory to android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to connect to MySql Server using the pache Commons DBCP (Database Connection Pooling) library, I face the following exception: java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: failed resolution of: ljava/lang/management/managementfactory.

I need to add java.lang.management.ManagementFactory to Android Studio because I wanna use Apache Commons DBCP (Database Connection Pooling) library to connect to the Mysql server.

```
public static Connection getConnection() {

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().penaltyLog().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(DBGlobalVariables.connURL, DBGlobalVariables.connUS, DBGlobalVariables.connPWD);
        PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
        GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(5);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(35);
        poolConfig.setMaxWait(Duration.ofMillis(7000));
        poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRuns(Duration.ofMillis(30000));
        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory, poolConfig);      //here, ManagementFactory must be available.
        poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
        PoolingDataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);

        return ConnectionE.conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ConnectionE.conn = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ConnectionE.conn = null;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android add java.lang.management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595814/android-add-java-lang-management-api)

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).